# No images when social sharing in SPA Angular

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular, twitter

I am using new meta service of Angular 4:

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private metaService: Meta) {
}

let newText = "Foo data. This is test data!:)";
    //metatags to publish this page at social nets
    this.metaService.addTags([
        // Open Graph data
        { property: 'og:type', content: "website" },
        { property: 'og:title', content: this.card.caption },
        { name: "twitter:title", content: this.card.caption },
        { property: 'og:description', content: this.card.caption + newText },
        { name: "twitter:description", content: this.card.caption + newText },
        { name: "mrc__share_description", content: this.card.caption + newText },
        { property: "og:url", content: window.location.href },
        { name: "twitter:url", content: window.location.href },
        { property: 'og:image', content: "http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg" },
        { property: 'og:image:width', content: "1200" },
        { property: 'og:image:height', content: "630" },
        { property: "twitter:image", content: "http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg" },
        { name: "twitter:image:src", content: "http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg" },
        { name: "twitter:card", content: "summary_large_image" },
        { name: "twitter:site", content: "fooContent" },
        { name: "twitter:creator", content: "fooContent" },
        { property: 'og:site_name', content: this.card.caption },
        { property: "article:published_time", content: "2017-04-17T05:59:00+01:00" },
        { property: "article:modified_time", content: "2017-04-17T05:59:00+01:00" },
        { property: "article:section", content: "Article Section" },
        { property: "article:tag", content: "Article Tag" },
        { property: "fb:admins", content: "414358988584020" },

        //mark up for Google
        { itemprop: "name", content: this.card.caption },
        { itemprop: "description", content: this.card.caption + newText },
        { itemprop: "image", content: "http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg" }
    ]);
```

and my page looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>Foo data. This is test data!:)">
    <meta name="mrc__share_description" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>Foo data. This is test data!:)"><meta property="og:url" content="http://fourl.com">
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://fourl.com"><meta property="og:image" content="http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"><meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg">
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:site" content="fooContent">
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="fooContent">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>">
    <meta property="article:published_time" content="2017-04-17T05:59:00+01:00">
    <meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-04-17T05:59:00+01:00">
    <meta property="article:section" content="Article Section">
    <meta property="article:tag" content="Article Tag"><meta property="fb:admins" content="414358988584020">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="<span style=&quot;color:red&quot;>Foo data. This is test data!:)</span>Foo data. This is test data!:)"><meta itemprop="image" content="http://usiter.com/uploads/20111118/zhivotnie+koshki+kartinka+s+malenkim+kotyonkom+35121656913.jpg">
</head>
```

However, there is no cool image, title of text and some content, when I insert to facebook, twitter or goolge.
What can be a reason of such behavior?

Comment: Is http://fourl.com the actual URL? That does not contain any Open graph meta data whatsoever.

Comment: @CBroe it is just an example. Sorry, but I cannot show the real url.

Comment: But your prior research has at least led you to the info that you can not set those meta tags via client-side JavaScript, right?

Comment: @CBroe no, when I open the page then I see all necessary meta tags!

Comment: That’s nice for you, but doesn’t make the Facebook scraper tool care about JS one bit. The OG meta tags are either in the HTML code that your server returns when the URL is requested - or they are not there at all.

Comment: @CBroe so there is no solution for this question?  Am I understood correctly that my server does not return social net metatags created by JavaScript to Facebook scraper tool?

Comment: Server-side JS would work, but that’s not what this is, right? _"so there is no solution for this question?"_ - remember how I asked if you did prior research …? The answer is a pre-rendering service of some sorts.

Comment: @CBroe am I understood correctly that I should prerender html like this service? https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-angular

Comment: Yes, either using such a package on your own server, or an external service like prerender.io

Comment: @CBroe please, make a reply and I will mark as an answer. It will simplify the future search for other people.

Comment: @downvoter what is a reason to downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set these Open Graph meta tags via client-side JavaScript - the Facebook scraper does not care about that, it only pays attention to the HTML code your server returns when the URL is requested.

For apps/sites that use a client-side framework like Angular to render their content, that means you need to also "pre-render" it (resp. at least the relevant OG meta tags, document can be empty otherwise), either using additional packages available for your system (like the https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-angular you mentioned; although the `_escaped_fragment_` syntax it mentions there is deprecated, see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification), or an external service like https://prerender.io/ (no affiliation; just know it as one common example.)